# Retrieving data from a text file on a different server using jQuery and JSONP

Tags: jquery, jsonp, getjson

Hi there i am trying to do something very simple, but as i am pretty new to JSONP i am struggling with it. All i want to do is retrieve some JSON from a text file in a different domain (hence my need to use JSONP to get round the cross domain issues). I am using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "http://www.topshop.com/aboutus/show.txt",
        success: returnedMessage
});

function returnedMessage(data) {
    console.log(data.message);
}
```

I know JSONP returns the JSON as a function, but i don't know how to print the resulting json objects to the console. I am pretty sure it can be done though as i can see in the NET tab of Firebug that it is returning the JSON as a response. In the Firebug console i am getting an invalid label message, which i think is because i am not treating the JSONP request in the right way. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Your JSONP format is not correct. The file contains JSON data, not JSONP data. The error message you get is because the browser is trying to run the object as code. You need to put a function call around the JSON data:

```
callback({
  "message": "This is coming from staging."
});
```

As the text file can't use the query string with the function name that is sent to it, you have to specify the function name using the `jsonpCallback` property instead:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'callback',
  url: "http://www.topshop.com/aboutus/show.txt",
  success: returnedMessage
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Guffa, but it didn't work. I just get the same old invalid label message in the Firebug console. I could be wrong on this but isn't the jsonpCallback property new for jQuery 1.4, if so then that may be why as we are currently using 1.3.2.

Comment: @El Guapo: If you still get the same error message you haven't corrected the format of the JSONP file. It's correct that jsonpCallback was added in 1.4, so you have to check what function name jQuery sends in the request so that you can use that name in the JSONP data.

Comment: OK, but how would i check what the function name jQuery is sending is as it is dynamic isn't it? Sorry if this is a stupid question but i am kind of new to this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.topshop.com/aboutus/show.txt?callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion milkshake, but that didn't work either. Again i get the invalid label message in the console.